# Trouble calling methods from a class/

Tags: java, class

Can someone tell me whats wrong with these codes ?

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    int roll_no;
    public void getDetails(String Name, int roll) {
        name = Name;
        roll_no = roll;
    }
}
```

and this

```
public class StudentRun {
    Student student = new Student();
    String n = "John";
    int r = 2;
    student.getDetails(n, r);
}
```

It shows the error:

> Multiple markers at this line

on the line where i call the `student.getDetails(n,r)`

Comment: You are missing the `main` method in `StudentRun` class: `public class StudentRun { public static void main(String[] args) { /* write your code here */}}`

Comment: You cant just write arbitrary code freely in a class. Code has to be **inside methods**. If you want your code to be executed when the program starts, put it into a **main** method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a method in a class without it being wrapped in a method.

Your Student class also lacks a **constructor** (a method that is called when the class is instantiated) and lacks the context of attribute visibility (public/protected/private).
The constructor must call itself as the class, in your case:

```
public class Student {
 protected String name;
 protected int roll_no;
 public Student(String Name, int roll) {
    this.name = Name;
    this.roll_no = roll;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return this.name
 } 
 ....
}
```

Once you have structured the class correctly, you need to do the following to instantiate it:

```
class OtherClass {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
 student = new Student("John", 42);
 System.out.println(student.getName());  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks to me you are calling the method without wraping it in a method in your class StudentRun. try using a constructor or some other method to call student.GetDetails

like
void callStudentRun
{

```
student.Getdetails();
```

}